# jQuery Validation - Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-validate

Not sure why this isn't working.
I'm sure you all know what I'm trying to achieve here.

When the script is run I get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `jquery.validate.js line:366` which refers to this hunk of code:

```
function delegate( event ) {
            var validator = $.data( this[ 0 ].form, "validator" ),
                eventType = "on" + event.type.replace( /^validate/, "" ),
                settings = validator.settings;
            if ( settings[ eventType ] && !this.is( settings.ignore ) ) {
                settings[ eventType ].call( validator, this[ 0 ], event );
            }
        }                           ^^^^ HERE
```

I'm using codeigniter2 framework so apologies if my form page doesn't make sense to some.

new_page.php (The relevant bit)

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url('admin/manage_pages/new_page'),
                            array('id' => 'new-page-form')) . PHP_EOL; ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Page Title', 'page-title',
                                'class="control-label"') . PHP_EOL; ?>
        <?php echo form_input(array(
                                'name' => 'page-title',
                                'id' => 'input-page-title',
                                'max-length' => '255',
                                'placeholder' => 'Enter Page Title',
                                'class' => 'form-control')) . PHP_EOL; ?>
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Url', 'slug', 'class="control-label"'); ?>
        <span id="input-slug-span" class="form-control">
            <span id="input-slug-static"><?php echo site_url(); ?></span>
            <?php echo form_input(array(
                                    'name' => 'slug',
                                    'id' => 'input-slug')); ?>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

and in new_page.validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  New Page Client Side Validation
    //
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $('#new-page-form').validate({

        onkeyup:true,

        rules: {
            'page-title': {
                required: true,
                remote: { 
                    url: 'new_title_exists',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'page-title': function() { return $("#input-page-title").val(); }
                    }
                }
            },
            'slug': {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'new_slug_exists',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'slug': function() { return $('#input-slug').val(); }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'page-title': {
                required: 'Page Title is required.',
                remote: 'Page Title must be unique.'
            },
            'slug': {
                required: 'A URL slug is required',
                remote: 'The URL must be unique.'
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Any help would be grateful! Cheers guys

Comment: `onkeyup: true` could potentially break the normal functioning of the plugin.  [As per documentation, _"a boolean true is **not** a valid value"_](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup).  That's because the `onkeyup` ability is already the default.

Comment: Although I'm familiar with PHP and CodeIgniter, this is not a problem with them... we need to troubleshoot your JavaScript.  So to assist you, we'll need to see the ***RENDERED*** HTML markup as seen by the browser.

Comment: Otherwise, until we see the relevant code, there appears to be nothing wrong in your `.validate()` method.

Comment: Also, whenever using jQuery Validate `remote` in a CodeIgniter project, you also have to send the CSRF token within the `data`.  You can pick this up from the hidden input element on your form.  You do **not** need to send the value of the input element being evaluated, however, because that data is already being sent by default.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks! Removing onkeyup fixed the issue although I'm getting a 500 internal server error when the data is posted?

Also, feel free to leave your answer below for a tick and a vote

Comment: The 500 error can be fixed by my last comment.  Posting answer now.

Comment: @Sparky you sir are a wizard!
I thought the csrf might have something to do with the request error but I'm not actually using codeigniter's form validation where the request is being sent but just a check in the database which returns TRUE or FALSE via json_encode
Do I still need to include the token?

Comment: You always have to send the token whenever the token is constructed within the form.  In other words, without `ajax()`, the token would be sent, so while using `ajax()`, you must send the same data because CI is expecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#new-page-form').validate({
    // onkeyup:true, // REMOVE THIS
    rules: {
        'page-title': {
            required: true,
            remote: {  // element's value IS always sent
                url: 'new_title_exists',
                type: 'post',
                data: {  // MUST send the CSRF Token Value
                    'csrftoken': function() {
                        return $('input[name="csrftoken"]').val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ....
```

- `onkeyup: true` could potentially break the normal functioning of the plugin. [As per documentation, *"a boolean true is not a valid value"*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup). That's because the `onkeyup` ability is already the default.
- Whenever using jQuery Validate `remote` method, or any `ajax()`, in a CodeIgniter project, you also have to send the CSRF token within the `data`, otherwise you will get a 500 server error. You can pick this up from the hidden input element on your form. You do not need to send the value of the input element being evaluated, however, because that data is already being sent by default.  Change the `name` above to match what's showing in the rendered source code of your form.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't get the value of the `csrf token` as it has no `ID` or `Class` and is also in a hidden input field but managed to do so from the cookie!

Comment: @MunkyMead, simply grab it by the `name`... `$('input[name="csrftoken"]')`