# JQuery Submit not called with remote verification

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to get my form to submit with jquery, and having a bit of trouble.

Why is my submit handler not being called?

I am trying to verify if a user name is already taken in the db using remote validation in the jquery rules section.  The php code to look up in the db works fine.  Very simplified code below.

If I remove the "remote" entry, the submit handler is called.  If the code has the remote entry in the rules, then the submit handler is not called.  From tracing through the JQuery code, it looks like there is some "pending request" preventing the submit from being called.

HTML:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<input type ='text' placeholder='Username' name="username" maxlength="25" size="20"  id="username" >

<input type="submit" value="submit" title="submit" >
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // ----------- Form Validation -----------------
 $("#test").validate({
      rules: {
         username: {
            required: true,
            minlength:5,
            maxlength:25,

            remote: {
        //      async: false,
        //     data: {
        //            'username': $('#username').val()
      //          },
    //           dataType: 'json',
                //dataType: "Text", 
                url: "/account/account-search/checkusername.php",
                type: "POST"
            }
        }

        },
        messages: {
        username: {
           required: "Please Enter A Username",
           remote: 'Username Not Available, Please Choose Another!'
        }
    },


    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        var username = $("#username").val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'username='+ username ;
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/account/artistRegistration.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false
            });

        return false;
    }


});

 });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//      $retval =  'true';
//      echo 1;
//      return true;
//  header('Content-Type: application/json');
//  echo json_encode($retval);
echo 'true';
//  return;
}
```

Comment: Tried returning the response from PHP various ways, text, json.  Tried adding async: false, no help.

Comment: `echo 'true'` is 100% correct.   I know it works and I can't see anything wrong with the code as you've posted it.  What does the error console tell you?  There should be details in  there about every `ajax` request.

Comment: By chance is this using CodeIgniter?  If so, you must pass the CSRF token value as a data parameter along with any `ajax` request.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28157693/594235

Comment: sparky,  nothing in the error console. I have tried with ie and ffx using built in debuggers. Someplace I am not looking that I should try?  Maybe a config issue on my box?  Not using codeignitor.   Gets to php code, runs it, and returns ok.

Comment: The `submitHandler` is only called when you click the submit button and the form evaluates as valid.  You're are not expecting it to be called when it shouldn't?  Then there has to be something else not being shown in your OP.  It works as long as your paths and URLs are correct.  You've made no coding mistakes and if there are no errors showing in your console, I don't know what else to tell you.  What version of jQuery Validate?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a problem in my apache config?  Most recent version of validate.

Comment: Not really sure how your Apache config could be affecting this, and again, there is nothing in your OP that would help us know that.

Comment: Fixed the problem.  Forgot about var_dump in db code.  Had to trace though ajax call and see mysqli results being returned.  Duh!