# Passing values to codeigniter controler through ajax

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I got a problem that's really ruining my life now. I'm trying to pass values to a codeigniter controller through Ajax.
I've read many things about it but I can't find why this is not working.

So I've made a form in a bootstrap modal windows to add a new member. The values are: first name, last name, email and passowrd.
I'm using jQuery validate to verify the infos and then I wanna pass the value to the controller.

```js
$('#addMember form').validate({  // initialize plugin
        rules: {
            lname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            mail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            repassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.input-group')
                .removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.addClass('valid').closest('.input-group')
                .removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // form validates so do the ajax
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: $(form).attr('method'),
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    // ajax done
                    // do whatever & close the modal
                    alert(status);
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
            return false; // ajax used, block the normal submit
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="addMember" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="addMemberForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('adminMembers/process_add_member');?>">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new member</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Last Name</span>
                <input name="lname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">First name</span>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email</span>
                <input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Password</span>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Password again</span>
                <input name="repassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add">Add</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I got a success message in an alert window so the ajax part is working.
Then I don't know how to use the values in my controller. 
If I try to print `$this->input->post('lname')` I got an empty value.

Any ideas please?

---

EDIT: Might be useful:

- My javascript code is placed right after the `</div><!-- /.modal -->`.
- The function add_Member in my controller looks like:

  ```
  public function process_add_member()
  {
      $this->membersManager->add_member();
  }
  ```
- And finally the model:

  ```
  public function add_member()
  {
      $name = $this->input->post('name');
      $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
      $email = $this->input->post('mail');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      return $this->db->set(array('name' => $name,
          'lname' => $lname,
          'login' => $email,
          'email' => $email,
          'password' => $password))->insert($this->table);
  }
  ```

As I said I tried to replace `$this->input->post()` by `$_POST[]` but still not working.

To finish I wanna ay that I've tried the same without using AJAX to pass the values and it is working. I need to use AJAX because I want the form to be in a bootstrap modal window.

The thing is that it seems my function `process_add_Member()` in the controller is not called. I can do anything in it and it won't happen.

Nobody? :( I really don't understand what is not working here.

HELP!
Is there someone that can help me please ?

Comment: What is value of `$(form).serialize()`?

Comment: Do you get anything from `var_dump($this->input->post())`?

Comment: The $(form).serialize( ) value is   lname=lnametest&name=fnametest&mail=test%40test.com&password=1234&repassword=1234

Comment: I don't get anything from var_dump($this->input->post( ))

Comment: Have you looked at your JavaScript console during the ajax requests for server errors?  If you're using CodeIgniter's built-in CSRF protection, then you **must** send the value of the CSRF token along with the Ajax data.

Comment: I've looked at the console and there is no error. I'm not using the CSRF, I didn't know it before you mentioned it.

Comment: Not a JavaScript error, but the response from the server.  When you do Ajax, the console should report back with the response from the server.  Anyway, with CodeIgniter, you must send the value of the CSRF token along with the Ajax data.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28157693/594235

Comment: I've moved the js code to the end of the page, right before the </body> tag and I worked just one time. It added a row in my database but it was only filled with 0. But it is not working anymore.

Comment: I have no messages in the Safari console. I tried also in firefox using firebug and the only message I got was because there is a password field in a http:// page.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for the tip I didn't know about it. I activated the CSRF on the config file and I added an hidden input field on my form to send the CSRF token. I still don't have any massages on the console. And it is still not working

Comment: What kind of troubleshooting are you doing?  Have you dumped the serialized data into your console *before* you send it?  Have you used PHP `var_dump()` to inspect the POST array *after* it arrives at the server?  Are you looking at your PHP error file?

Comment: Something seems very wrong with this:  `$this->membersManager->add_member()`.  If your model is called `membersManager`, then it should look like this:  `$this->membersManager_model->add_member()`.  Are you properly loading the model?  `$this->load->model('membersManager_model');`  We cannot see the beginning of the Model or Controller files to know if you've constructed them properly.  Please review: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: If CSRF protection was not activated in the first place, then it's not blocking your Ajax, and turning it on is not going to make any difference.

Comment: @Sparky As I said I've tried without AJAX and it's working so it doesn't seem there is any problems on my controller and model. I'm loading the model on my controller this way `$this->load->model('members_model', 'membersManager');` so I can call it using membersManager instead of members_model. I just think it's prettier ;)  I used `var_dump()` but as I said it seems like I can do anything in my controller it wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing data using the form serialize method insteading of using `$this->input->post()` retrieve the post value directly `$_POST['<input_name>']` .

Hope this will solve your problem since.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `form_open()` helper function in your view, so that the CSRF token is included as a hidden field.

And in general: you should always use the helper functions and classes whenever possible. There is no use in working with a framework if you don't use the provided functions.